# how to connect to mongodb server via ssh tunnel with Proxy Jump (Bastion Host)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ssh-tunnel, mongodb-compass, bastion-host

I have an ssh config file like this.
I have a proxy jump to host1 from test2.

```
Host host1
  Hostname xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  Port 2222
  User xxxx
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  KeepAlive yes
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 30

Host test2
  Hostname xx.xxx.xx.xxx
  ProxyCommand  ssh.exe host1  -q -W %h:%p host1
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert
  KeepAlive yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 30
```

**My mongo db host : xxx-nonprod.cluster-xx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com**

I have to Use SSH Tunneling to Mongodb using Host **test2**, But it uses Proxy Jump using **ProxyCommand**

I want to connect to mongodb using SSH Tunneling with a **Mongo DB Compass** and also with **node js mongoose**.

**How Can I connect using the Mongo DB Compass?**

[image]

Here I don't have an option to enter **ProxyCommand** details.

**How Can I connect using node js?**

I am using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh),  I have a reference code ,

```
var config = {
    username:'ubuntu',
    host:'xx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('~/.ssh/cert'),
    port:22,
    dstPort:27017
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
  
});
```

Here as well how can I enter **ProxyCommand** details here? Or please suggest any node js package which solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to connect to the database now.

1. Make a tunnel through Bastion to the Database from the terminal.

   **ssh -L 27017:{mongodb-host}:27017 host1**
2. I am able to connect to database via the tunnel from localhost in another terminal.

   **mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017  --username {username} --password {password}**

So I am able to connect through mongoose too using connection string.
**mongodb://dbadmin:{username}:{password}@localhost:27017**

Comment: You may have put username twice. ie:  `mongodb://{username}:{password}@localhost:27017` worked for me. Cheers,

Comment: You may also want to add `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames` (as described [here](https://medium.com/@Dylan.Wang/mongodb-4-x-the-server-certificate-does-not-match-the-host-name-50d8afeb6162).)
I had to add it due to `Hostname: 127.0.0.1 does not match SAN(s)` error.